# llvm-cov shows braces as uncovered

Tags: clang, code-coverage, gcov, lcov, llvm-cov

Our project migrated from `gcc` to `clang` so we changed coverage tool from `gcov` to `llvm-cov`.

It's led to many false-positives of this type:

[image]

While with gcc it worked as expected

[image]

I tried clang-12, 15, 16 and results are equal

```
Capturing coverage data from /home/user/build_release     
Found LLVM gcov version 16.0.0, which emulates gcov version 4.2.0
```

Are there any ideas what can I do with this uncovered braces?

PS: of course I disabled optimization with -O0 flag